# VB script to delete folder in U drive

Tags: vbscript

```
Const DeleteReadOnly = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.DeleteFile("\\servername\public\*.*"), DeleteReadOnly
objFSO.DeleteFolder("\\servername\public\*.*")
```

When I ran it on the server, it said:

```
Script: C:\temp\deleteU.vbs
Line: 5
Char:1
Error: Permission denied
Code: 800A0046
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

I have full Admin access to the server.
When I manually delete all the folders in Public folder, no issue.

Comment: line:5? in a four line script? Which line is line number 5? Why `DeleteReadOnly` is outside the parenthesis? Maybe is it line number 5?

Comment: do you mean I should put 
 objFSO.DeleteFile("\\servername\public\*.*", DeleteReadOnly)

Line 5 is create a folder:
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("\\servername\public\Scan_NQAC")